# Where to download TFS 2010 Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I only find Beta 2 candidates. Where to download the RTM version?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link: <s>[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8bb22356-7dfb-4999-9d76-43abddcf6eec&displaylang=en)</s>

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20506

Comment: Wow, that is quite a download for a basic tool? Is there also a free edition as I noticed this is only a trial?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: This link is now dead! Damn visual studio, what if you need to do some legacy work... NOT EVERYONE ALWAYS USING THE LATEST CODE, MICROSOFT!! ARRRGH